# How to detect day pass in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

How to detect day pass (23:59-00:00) in Android? I'm used Broadcast receiver but it is only working when set a date from settings.

```
<receiver android:name=".DateChangedReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Can't you start some service on application start and use Alarms (and Calendar)? So that your service tells your application when should action occur... http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to set an alarm at midnight.

You'll need to set it after it fires, and also if you receive the DATE_CHANGED, TIME_SET or TIMEZONE_CHANGED events.

Comment: what if I want to create a notification every midnight, can ı use alarmManager again? I don't want an alarım

Comment: read documentation about using alarms (don't worry it will not ring every time) http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: The AlarmManager handles alerts to applications, it doesn't notify the user. Once you receive the alarm notification in your app, you can notify the user however you like.